# Python + pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm really new to python, just playing around.
I have script that gets

> ------- received message ------- {"e":"24hrMiniTicker","E":1634212481158,"s":"ADAUSDT","c":"2.19200000","o":"2.12100000","h":"2.20000000","l":"2.10000000","v":"119875239.00000000","q":"259043876.72690000"}

from Binance stream. I'm able to print out this line in terminal and add it to an array, but I want to run this script in the background and have another script fill a pandas dataframe with that data.

1st Script:

```
import websocket
import numpy as np
import config
import pandas as pd
from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *
message_store = np.array
SYMBOL = "adausdt"
SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/" + SYMBOL + "@miniTicker"
client = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET, tld='us')
def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')


def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')


def on_message(ws, message):
    print('------- received message -------')
    print(message)
    message_store.append(message)
    #x = len(message_store)
    
    #print(x)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)  
ws.run_forever()
```

2nd Script:

```
from getprice import message_store
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=message_store) 
print(dataframe)
```

> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Any ideas how to do this the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are constructing the message_store wrong, you are assigning the consructor to it instead of an instance of np.array. second, in this case you should use a regular list instead of np.array because:

1. you don't know the size of the final array when you construct it
2. The array contain an object and not any kind of numeric data

so you should use:

```
message_store = []
```

instead of

```
message_store = np.array
```

Small example:

```
import pandas as pd
lst = []
lst.append({"e": "24hrMiniTicker", "E": 1634212481158, "s": "ADAUSDT", "c": "2.19200000", "o": "2.12100000", "h": "2.20000000", "l": "2.10000000",
            "v": "119875239.00000000", "q": "259043876.72690000"})
lst.append({"e": "24hrMiniTicker", "E": 1634212481158, "s": "ADAUSDT", "c": "2.19200000", "o": "2.12100000", "h": "2.20000000", "l": "2.10000000",
            "v": "119875239.00000000", "q": "259043876.72690000"})
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df.head(5))
print(df["e"])
```

Comment: I assume this is normal behaviour

  File "/Users/renaatvandewiele/Desktop/GIT/python/pythontrade/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    df = df["e"]
  File "/Users/renaatvandewiele/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/renaatvandewiele/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py", line 388, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'e'

since the dataframes has two columns now  instead of the columns bu lst.append

Comment: use print(df.columns) and make sure you have a column named 'e'